# How do I install ASP.NET Core 2.0 on MacOS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app on a Mac, but it doesn't build for the following reason:

```
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
```

I have installed Visual Studio for Mac (Community) v. 7.6.8. When I run `dotnet --info` I get:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.302
 Commit:    9048955601

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.13
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.13-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.2
  Commit:  811c3ce6c0

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.301 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.302 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I see that I don't have the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.* runtime, but I don't know how to install it. I've downloaded the binaries from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.0, but there are no instructions on what to do with the files.

The app I'm trying to build/run is here: https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-mvc-2 (folder "08 - SportsStore/SportsStore").

Comment: I found that the problem was with the unit test project: it didn't have a NuGet reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.All. When I added the reference, the solution built normally.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - completely misread your question - looks like [this](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.0) is the download you need, specifically https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.0.9-macos-x64-asp.net-core-runtime-binaries

You can make your project target netcoreapp2.1 instead of netcoreapp2.0 by editing your .csproj file, like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You checked that you have the 2.1 SDK installed, but with that SDK you can target any framework up to 2.1, including 2.0.

If you really want your app to be on 2.0, the other alternative is to downgrade your aspnet package to a 2.0.x version e.g. [2.0.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.0.9). You can see which version of the framework each package requires under the `Dependencies` section on nuget.org

Comment: The ASP.NET package for the project is already 2.0.0. It seems like I need to install the runtime on my machine, partly in this location "/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All". At the moment, that location contains folders "2.1.1" and "2.1.2", but not "2.0.0".